# Difference beetween the IIB V10 MQTT Nodes and MQ MQTT

Tags: ibm-mq, mqtt

With Version 10 of IBM Integration Bus (IIB) a MQTT subscribe and publish node is available in the Toolkit. If you use IIB V10 with IBM MQ one can also use the IBM MQ MQTT implementation. Is there any recommendation which one to use or can the MQTT subscribe and publish nodes of the Toolkit be configured to make use the MQ MQTT implementation?

Comment: Both IIB  and IBM MQ have a MQTT broker available.  With IBM MQ the IBM MQ Telemetry (MQTT) is a separately chargeable component unless you have the IBM MQ Advanced license which includes IBM MQ Telemetry.  The MQTT broker that is part of IIB has no extra charge. The IIB MQTT Pub and Sub nodes can connect to the MQTT broker from IIB or IBM MQ.

Comment: Klaus,  I'll format those details into a answer with a few links if you would be willing to accept it.